# What kind of spider is this?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I spotted this spider in my garden (Northern UK). The body is about 20mm long, and it's made a sizeable (50cm) web on a wall.

[image]

There's another semi-identical one on a nearby hedge.

[image]

What kind is it?

Comment: Do you have any larger or clearer pictures of it?

Comment: @MattDMo - Larger, yes. Clearer, not especially. Hang fire while I go and get some more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks for the pictures! That's the **European Garden Spider** (*[Araneus diadematus](http://www.uksafari.com/cross.htm)*)

They are most commonly seen from June to October, but they reach a peak around right now.  This species is all over UK, and is widespread in gardens, woodland, and meadows.  Here is another picture for reference:

[image: Araneus diadematus]

[Fun Fact](http://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/garden-spider): After laying their eggs in late autumn, the females die and only the eggs make it through winter.  Upon hatching, they look quite different from the adults:

[image: Araneus diadematus babies]

Comment: Why have I never seen these little beasties before?

Comment: @Valorum - I'm truly shocked that you haven't, actually.  They seem to be one of the most common spiders around my parts (West Midlands) at the very least.  Although they do seem to have less of a tendency to end up indoors than most others.

Comment: @Jules - Never seen them. We get loads of house spiders, crane flies, daddy long-legs, wasps, ladybirds and the occasional bumble-bee but never one of these.